# Selectively negate elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for some help around 'how to selectively negate the values of an array' in numpy.

Already tried, `numpy.where()` and `numpy.negative` but not able to implement condition on selected few.

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.arange(11)
arr
```

---

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Say I want to just negate all elements of the array that are between 2 and 8

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  -3,  -4,  -5,  -6,  -7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Answer (score 8):

Use bitwise AND to create a mask, and multiply by `-1`:

```
m = (arr > 2) & (arr < 8)
arr[m] *= -1
```

```
array([ 0,  1,  2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
condition = np.logical_and(arr >= 2, arr <= 8)
arr = np.select([~condition, condition], [arr, -arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(11)

arr[3:9] = np.multiply(arr[3:9],-1)

print(arr)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment on why would your answer help the OP

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for. You can use either of the approaches.

```
index = arr.where((arr>2) & (arr<8))
arr[index] *= -1
print(arr)
```

Or

```
arr[(arr>2) & (arr<8)] *= -1
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This snipped should be helpful to you

```
c=np.where((arr>2) & (arr<8) ,arr*-1,arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
a = np.random.random(size=10)
a[2:8] = np.negative(a[2:8])
```

Comment: Add substantial content to your answer to make it valid because 4 more answer are given and you want to best answer, right?! End of Review.